# Inner Join in VB - two tables SQL

Tags: vba, visual-studio

Pulling my hair out trying to understand what I am doing wrong.
Trying to display in a Data Grid Object the contents of:
major & studstanding --> Students Table &
quiz1, quiz2, exam1, exam2 --> MIS Table

Students Table primary key = StudentID / 
MIS Table primary key = StudentID

dim da as new oledbdataadapter("select students.major, students.studstanding, avg(quiz1) as quiz1avg, avg(quiz2) as quiz2avg, avg(exam1) as exam1avg, avg(exam2) as exam2avg FROM mis INNER JOIN students on mis.studentid = students.studentid", dc)

results in: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'major' as part of an aggregate function.

I am not trying to perform an aggregate function on major!

Visual Studio 2015 --> Visual Basic --> Windows Form

Comment: you need to group by students.major, students.studstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use GroupBy in your query to get rid of this error

dim da as new oledbdataadapter("select students.major, students.studstanding, avg(quiz1) as quiz1avg, avg(quiz2) as quiz2avg, avg(exam1) as exam1avg, avg(exam2) as exam2avg FROM mis INNER JOIN students on mis.studentid = students.studentid GROUP BY students.major, students.studstanding", dc)